# More entries needed

Tags: cognito-forms

I think I am going to need more than 10,000 entries this month.

Is there any way I can just buy more entries?

Or get billed once they're submitted?

What happens if we reach the limit - will it just not accept any more?

If we change to the 99/month plan, and get more than 10,000 entries, and then go back down to Team will it retain the overflow of entries?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) [Terms of Service](https://www.cognitoforms.com/terms):

> **Entries** - When the number of new entries created for an organization for a given month exceeds the limits for the current plan, these additional entries will be "locked".  Cognito Forms will not prevent entries from being created and will not affect form submissions.  These "locked" entries can be "unlocked" within 30 days by upgrading to a plan that provides a sufficient number of monthly entries.

As stated, new submissions will not be blocked if your organization exceeds this limit and neither will you be charged for overages.  If you want to unlock these entries, you can upgrade to the next higher plan for the current month and downgrade the following month if you anticipate lower volumes in the future.  Plans are prorated as well, so you would only pay the higher rate for the remainder of the current month and your organization receives a credit if you downgrade in the middle of a month.